# Whether the windows side bar explorer in windows explorer is tree view control or custom control?

Tags: c#

[image]I trying to create a Tree View Folder Explorer in Win Form, Similar to the windows side bar explorer. I am confused that the windows side bar explorer is tree view control or custom control.

If it is Tree View Control,Then how do i implement like Tree View with Navigation Arrow ,Drive Icon and Folder Icon ?.

I tried what all answers gave, And here is my output ..
[image]

But i want an icon image should look like this ,Means that the icon image should have transparent background and without distortion.[image]

Comment: What are you talking about exactly?  A screenshot would be helpful.  A standard treeview component can easily hold various icons.  Each node can have a separate icon.

Comment: @HaukurHaf Review please

Comment: Looks like `TreeView` that can be made using `Wpf` without problem.

Comment: Agree, looks like a basic treeview to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, Drive Icon and Folder Icon  - Yes thats possible.

1. Add a image list to the view - add all icons to this image list.
2. Set this Image list as the 'ImageList' of the the tree view
3. Go to nodes in tree view & you can chose the selected & deselected image of each node

To get rid of the '+' / '-' sign - Set ShowPlusMinus property of treeview to False

To get rid of the lines - Set ShowShowRootLines property of treeview to False

Navigation Arrows (the ones which toggle on expanding & collapsing) -

1. Add the arrow icons to the same image list
2. Set 'StateImageList' property of the tree view to the same image list
3. Go to nodes in tree view & you can chose the StateImage

But to change the Icon on expanding and collapsing, I think you'll have to write an event handler like this -

```
    private void treeView1_AfterExpand(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Node.StateImageIndex = 0; // assuming 0 is the const for expanded navigation 
    }

    private void treeView1_AfterCollapse(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Node.StateImageIndex = 1; // assuming 1 is the const for collapsed navigation 
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: But then how do i add navigation arrow in front of the icon ?

Comment: By navigation arrow you mean the Arrow which toggle when when u collapse or expand a tree node ? ('>' & 'V').... One moment I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer for the  navigation arrow thing you asked

Comment: okay then , How do i add event handler for state image click event?

Comment: would u like to handle state image click event to change the icon - collapsed or expanded ? To change the icon to collapsed or expanded, you dont have to handle state image click event you have to handle - "AfterExpand" & "AfterCollapse" available at treeview. I have handled the same in my example above

Comment: I see, your icons have a whitish border...please try this - Go to the imagelist properties & set the 'TransparentColor' property to exactly the same color like the border.

Comment: No it does not seems to be working, Results are same.

Comment: The same Heart icon was used in image list and  picture box were shown in the question  respectively.

Comment: Could you upload the icon file.

Comment: http://www.iconarchive.com/show/flatastic-2-icons-by-custom-icon-design/favorite-icon.html

Comment: I saw the issue, but I'm sorry I dont know how to fix it... I guess I always worked with straight icons... the heart shape has curves so may be thats the issue

Comment: OK thanks for your support and i going to create one myself